# How to access properties of another table in one-to-many relationship using django template language?

Tags: django, django-models, django-templates, django-views

I would like to use properties from different tables connected with one-to-many relationship in hardcoded img src in the template.

Models.py:

```
    class Offers(models.Model):
        province = models.CharField()
        district = models.CharField()
        location = models.CharField()

    class OffersPhotos(models.Model):
        offers_id = models.ForeignKey('Offers')
        order = models.IntegerField()
```

Views.py:

```
def index(request):

    latest_offers = Offers.objects.order_by('-creation_date')[:5]

    context_dict = {'latest_offers': latest_offers}

    return render(request, 'something.html', context_dict)
```

Template:

```
{% for offer in latest_offers %}

    <img src="http://something.com/{{offer.id}}/{{offer.offersphotos.id}}.jpg">

{% endfor %}
```

{{offer.id}} works perfectly but how can I access id of the photo that has order=1 in the same line?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think is not a good idea to query all the `offerphotos` given an `offer` and getting the first one in a template.

Instead you can define a property in your `Offers` class, soy you can get the first `photo`.

It should be something like this:

**Models.py**

```
class Offers(models.Model):
    province = models.CharField()
    district = models.CharField()
    location = models.CharField()
    def first_offerphoto(self):
        return self.offerphotos_set.first()
```

**Template**

```
{% for offer in latest_offers %}

    <img src="http://something.com/{{offer.id}}/{{offer.first_offerphoto.id}}.jpg">

{% endfor %}
```

Although you can still using the logics in your `template`:

```
<img src="http://something.com/{{offer.id}}/{{offer.offerphotos_set.first.id}}.jpg">
```

But i rather doing all `queries` *before* displaying info into `templates`

Comment: Beat me to it. Just want to add tho that the OP's question ``offerphotos`` should be ``offerphotos_set`` as you have pointed out. They could also do a ``{% with offer.offerphotos_set.all|first as image %}`` works works in the same way.